# Call MVC View from login

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a login and I validated the data with AJAX then I Call my view with ajax.
The problem is when I call the view from AJAX the view does't show but when I write the url from Fire Fox the system show me the view correctly.
I have not idea why happen this.

THis is part of my code, help me please.

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    Logueo();
});

function Logueo() {
    $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        var correo = $("#Correo").val();
        var Contrasena = $("#Contrasena").val();
        var Correcto = false;
        var dir = window.location.href;

        if (correo == "" || Contrasena == "") {
            $('#modalMensaje').modal('show');
            $('#mensaje').html("Usuario o Contraseña Invalido");
        } else {
            Correcto = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: dir+"/Home/Index",
                data: { Correcto: Correcto },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function () {
                    console.log("ENTRO");
                }
            });

        }



    });

}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index(bool? Correcto)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Correcto == true)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Inicio");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }



    }

    public ActionResult Inicio() {
        return PartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
```

I want to call my Home view after my logging

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>HOME</h2>
```

This is an example I'm doing to learn how to use MVC and move from a login to a main screen

Somebody can help me to find the problem ?

Thanks :D

Edit:

I changed the code that you said me and is close to functioning but the HTML that the success return doesn't show very well

I attach 2 images, first one is the original html and the second one is the result

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guo6c.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0UGA.png)

This is my _layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie ie9" lang="en" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="INS 24/7" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="DMR" />

    <title>Red Medica</title>


    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/Style/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/Style/css/skins/INS247.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/Style/css/my-custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/theme")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bebasneue")


    <!--JavaScript-->
</head>
<body class="sidebar-fixed topnav-fixed dashboard">

    <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">

        <!-- TOP BAR -->
        <div class="top-bar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <a href="#" class="pull-left toggle-sidebar-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                    <!-- logo -->
                    <div class="pull-left left logo">
                        @*<img src="~/Content/img/Logo.png" alt="" />*@

                    </div>
                    <!-- end logo -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /container -->
        </div>
        <!-- END TOP BAR -->
        <!-- LEFT SIDEBAR -->
        <div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="left-sidebar" class="left-sidebar" style="background-color:#222d32">
            <!-- main-nav -->
            <div class="sidebar-scroll">
                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <ul class="main-menu">
                        <li >
                            <a href="/Home/Index">
                                <i class="fa fa-home">
                                </i><span class="text">Inicio</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle">
                                <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i><span class="text">Imagen</span>
                                <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/Imagen/CargarImagen">
                                        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload">
                                        </i><span class="text">Cargar Imagen</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/Imagen/ActualizarImagen">
                                        <i class="fa fa-refresh">
                                        </i><span class="text">Actualizar Imagen</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/Imagen/BorrarImagen">
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o">
                                        </i><span class="text">Borrar Imagen</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- /main-nav -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT WRAPPER -->
        <div id="main-content-wrapper" class="content-wrapper ">

            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT WRAPPER -->
    </div>
    <!-- END WRAPPER -->
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>


    <script src="~/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/king-common.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/stat/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/raphael/raphael-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/stat/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/stat/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/stat/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/stat/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/stat/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/jquery-mapael/jquery.mapael.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/raphael/maps/usa_states.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/king-chart-stat.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/king-table.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/king-components.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Imagen/AgregarImagen.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/load-image.all.min.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are returning html?  `dataType: 'JSON',` says the response should be json.  Those two things do not match.

Comment: This will for sure not work, instead try if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) { return View(“YourViewName”); }

Comment: I changed the code that you said me and is close to functioning but the HTML that the success return doesn't show very well

Comment: Another Idea ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
success: function () {
    console.log("ENTRO");
}
```

You are discarding the results of the AJAX call. No wonder nothing is displayed.

After the AJAX call succeeds, you have to do something with the results. What you do depends on what is returned.  If the returned data is intended to be JSON, you will need to parse the JSON and map the data into fields on your page. If on the other hand you wish to return HTML, you can update the page. For example, you could do this to refresh the whole page:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("html").html(data);   
}
```

Note: If you intended to return HTML, you will need to set the dataType correctly, as Taplar has commented.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code. The below javascript code will help you with solving your problem.

```
//JS - directly define this in the script tag, no need to have the document ready and the function.

$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
    var correo = $("#Correo").val();
    var Contrasena = $("#Contrasena").val();
    var Correcto = false;
    var dir = window.location.href;

    if (correo == "" || Contrasena == "") {
        $('#modalMensaje').modal('show');
        $('#mensaje').html("Usuario o Contraseña Invalido");
    } else {
        Correcto = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Index", //You don't need to do the dir+"/Home/Index" if you are requesting to same origin
            data: { Correcto: Correcto },
            //dataType: 'JSON', No need of this
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (res) {
                $("body").html(res); //Replaces the body of the page with the newly returned html or whatever it returns.
                console.log(res)
            }
        });
    }
}); 


//MVC 

[HttpPost] //Your post action should have the [HttpPost] attribute
public ActionResult Index(bool? Correcto)
{
    try
    {
        if (Correcto == true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Inicio");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you would need the complete code (ASP.NET MVC + JavaScript).